# groovy.lang.MissingPropertyException: No such property: basePath for class: Script466 in Apache jmeter

Tags: groovy, jmeter, jsr223

I need to share few variables between two thread groups in an Apache jmeter project. I found that variables cannot be shared between thread groups and I have to use properties. I have written the below script inside a JSR223 PreProcessor in the first thread group to set the property values. It runs without any exception.

```
@Grab('org.yaml:snakeyaml:1.17')

import org.yaml.snakeyaml.Yaml;
import org.apache.jmeter.services.FileServer;

String baseDir = FileServer.getFileServer().getBaseDir()

Yaml ymlparser = new Yaml()

Map config = ymlparser.load((baseDir+"/config/tool.yaml" as File).text)

String base_path = baseDir + "/data/" + trafficConfig.find{it.key=="name"}?.value

${__setProperty(basePath, base_path)};
```

If I log the value of the property 'basePath' from the same JSR223 PreProcessor, it will return the correct value.

Then I'm reading the property value from a JSR223 PreProcessor in the second thread group like below.

```
${__property(basePath, base_path)}
log.info( base_path );
```

It will through the below exception in jmeter log.

> 2019-11-02 18:54:19,353 ERROR o.a.j.m.JSR223PreProcessor: Problem in
>   JSR223 script, JSR223 PreProcessor javax.script.ScriptException:
>   javax.script.ScriptException: groovy.lang.MissingPropertyException: No
>   such property: basePath for class: Script470  at
>   org.codehaus.groovy.jsr223.GroovyScriptEngineImpl.eval(GroovyScriptEngineImpl.java:162)
>   ~[groovy-all-2.4.16.jar:2.4.16]   at
>   javax.script.AbstractScriptEngine.eval(AbstractScriptEngine.java:233)
>   ~[?:1.8.0_221]    at
>   org.apache.jmeter.util.JSR223TestElement.processFileOrScript(JSR223TestElement.java:225)
>   ~[ApacheJMeter_core.jar:5.1.1 r1855137]   at
>   org.apache.jmeter.modifiers.JSR223PreProcessor.process(JSR223PreProcessor.java:44)
>   [ApacheJMeter_components.jar:5.1.1 r1855137]  at
>   org.apache.jmeter.threads.JMeterThread.runPreProcessors(JMeterThread.java:935)
>   [ApacheJMeter_core.jar:5.1.1 r1855137]    at
>   org.apache.jmeter.threads.JMeterThread.executeSamplePackage(JMeterThread.java:537)
>   [ApacheJMeter_core.jar:5.1.1 r1855137]    at
>   org.apache.jmeter.threads.JMeterThread.processSampler(JMeterThread.java:486)
>   [ApacheJMeter_core.jar:5.1.1 r1855137]    at
>   org.apache.jmeter.threads.JMeterThread.run(JMeterThread.java:253)
>   [ApacheJMeter_core.jar:5.1.1 r1855137]    at
>   java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748) [?:1.8.0_221]

Comment: I'm using apache jmeter version 5.1.1 and I have added apache ivy-2.5.0.jar file to the lib.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `props` to set property

```
props.put("basePath", base_path);
```

Don't use `${}` syntax in JSR223 components

Comment: And I should retrieve property basePath using props.get("basePath"). That worked. Thanks